# How can I relate between street and city in OSM imported data into SQL?

Tags: openstreetmap, sql-server

I've used OSM2MSSQL to fill db with 2 cities streets. Now I have the following tables in my DB :

```
tNode 
tNodeTag
tRelation
tRelationMember
tRelationTag 
tTagText 
tWay 
tWayCreation 
tWayTag
```

How can I get all the streets that are in a specific city ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291246/open-street-map-streets-by-city

Comment: You would need a Cities table with at least attributes for name and spatial extent (as a polygon). Then you would perform a join between Streets and Cities based on spatial overlap/contains. The query result is all roads with a corresponding city name attribute. For a single city [the documentation example for STOverlaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929274.aspx) should be very close to your needed query.

Comment: Thank you bhell.
What I did is creating a geographic POLYGON and using STContains on roads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bhell suggested I did the following query to get the streets in a specific city:

1. Creating polygon of city in QGIS
2. Using SQL Query

   DECLARE @POI geography;
   SET @POI = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(36.81120 -1.27531)', 4326);

   DECLARE @BOUNDS geography;
   SET @BOUNDS = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((36.68936531 -1.354740152,36.93951706 -1.354740152,36.93951706 -1.196323211,36.68936531 -1.196323211,36.68936531 -1.354740152))', 4326)

   SELECT [ID]
          ,[NAME]
          ,[geom]
          ,@BOUNDS.STContains(a.geom)
   FROM [TABLE_STREETS] as a
   WHERE @BOUNDS.STContains(a.geom) = 1

Thank you for your help.